# How to fetch a certain number of records from paginated dynamodb table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to work with the first 50 records or 1st scan page returned from the **get_paginator** method.

This is how i scan through the table and get paginated results over which i loop and do some post processing.

```py
dynamo_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
paginator = dynamo_client.get_paginator("scan")

  for page in paginator.paginate(TableName=table_name):
      yield from page["Items"]
```

Is it possible to only work on say the 1st scanned page and explicitly mention 2nd page onwards? Summing it up, i am trying to query the first page results in one lambda function and the 2nd page specifically using another lambda function. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the `NextToken` to your other Lambda, somehow.

On the `paginator` response, there is a `NextToken` property. You can then pass that in the config of the `paginator.paginate()` call.

Somewhat contrived example:

```py
dynamo_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
paginator = dynamo_client.get_paginator("scan")
token = ""

  # Grab the first page
  for page in paginator.paginate(TableName=table_name):
      # do some work
      dowork(page["Items"])
      # grab the token
      token = page["NextToken"]
      # stop iterating after the first page for some reason
      break

  # This will continue to iterator where the last iterator left off
  for page in paginator.paginate(TableName=table_name, PaginationConfig= 'StartingToken': token }):
      # do some work
      dowork(page["Items"])
```

Let's say you were trying to use a Lambda to iterate over all your DynamoDB items in a table. You could have the iterator run until a time limit, break, then queue up next Lambda function, passing along the `NextToken` for it to resume with.

You can learn more via the [API doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Paginator.Scan) which details what this does or see some further examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/python/WorkingWithScans/scan_with_paginator.py).

Comment: Great example Chris. I would also suggest using a segmented Scan where each Lambda works on a segment of the table, rather than trying to split pages: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/python/WorkingWithScans/scan_parallel.py

Comment: Thank you so much Chris & Lee, I will try these solutions and update the thread with my results soon.